# How to access Azure DevOps deploy comments from REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been able to successfully access all kinds of details around a release in Azure DevOps by leveraging the .NET client libraries (ex: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client) that wrap the REST API.  However, I can't seem to find what the object/property combination is that I would use to retrieve the comments that can be entered when kicking off a deployment to a specific environment.

To be clear, the comments I'm looking for are entered by hovering over an environment of a release and selecting "Deploy". On the right hand side there is a dialog in which comments can be entered and then another "Deploy" button is selected to kickoff the deployment.

Does anyone have any ideas on how these deployment comments can be read by using the Azure DevOps REST APIs or .NET client libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get release history REST API to get deploy comments:

`Get  https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/Release/releases/{Release Id}/history?api-version=6.1-preview.1`

Here is my sample:
[image]